# Allocating memory for array of pointers of int dynamically

Tags: c++, pointers

If I want to dynamically allocate memory for array of pointers of int, how can I achieve this requirement?

Suppose I declare an array of pointers of int like this:

```
int (* mat)[];
```

Is there a way I can allocate memory for K number of pointers dynamically and assign it to mat? If I do

```
mat = new int * [K];
```

It gives error : `cannot convert 'int**' to 'int (*)[]' in assignment`. I understand this memory allocation is implicitly got converted to int **. Is there any way to allocate memory for above scenario?

Even when I try to assignment of statically allocated array of pointers of int to array of pointers of int, like this:

```
int (*mat)[] = NULL;
int (* array_pointers)[26];
mat = array_pointers;
```

Compilation gives this error: `cannot convert 'int (*)[26]' to 'int (*)[]' in assignment`.

Can someone please explain to me why this is an error or why it should be an error?

Comment: is this `C` or `C++`?

Comment: If C++, you may try to use `std::vector<int*>`

Comment: In C you can simplify use int ** mat; for array of pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, `int (* mat)[];` is a pointer to array of `int` with unspecified size (not an array of pointers). In C++ it is an error, the dimension cannot be omitted in C++.

Your question says `new int *[K]` so I assume this is really a C++ question. The expression `new T[n]` evaluates to a `T *` already, there is no implicit conversion.

The code to allocate an array of null pointers using `new` is:

```
int **mat = new int *[10]();
```

Then `mat` points to the first one of those. Another option (less commonly used) is:

```
int * (*mat)[10] = new int *[1][10]();
```

where `*mat` designates the entire array of 10 pointers.

NB. This sort of code is not useful for anything except demonstration purposes perhaps, whatever you are trying to do has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, in some cases, arrays and pointers are interchabgable.
`int*[]` decays in to `int**`.

To dynamically allocate an array, use:

```
int* mat;
// ...
mat = new int[size];
// ...
delete[] mat;
```

Note that you need to `delete` all memory you take with `new`, or else you'll leak memory.
It's not always easy to do.

C++ has a thing called RAII to help.
To use RAII (meaning all resources taken in a scope will be released when the scope ends), put the `new` in a classes constructor, and `delete` in the destructor.

The STL has some comtainers ready for you to use.
Look in to `std::vector`.

---

If you want an *array of pointers* as opposed to a dynamic array, the syntax is more like

```
int** arr = new int[size];
arr[i] = &val;
// ...
delete[] arr;
```

Don't forget to initialize each pointer in the array!

If `size` is known at compile time, this can be rewritten as:

```
std::array<int*, size> arr;
arr[i] = &val;
```

No need to delete, and it checks overflows.

If `size` is unknown at compile time, you can do:

```
std::vector<int*> arr;
arr.resize(size);
arr[i] = &val;
```

Comment: This allocates an array of int. OP asked for an array of pointers to int.

Comment: Your second suggestion doesn't compile . The result of `new` is a prvalue and `&` cannot be applied to it.

Comment: Still not fixed .. perhaps check with a compiler

Comment: ideone suppresses error messages sometimes. The code in your link is OK but different to what you have in your answer. Also, it can only be rewritten with `std::array` if size is known at compile-time (unclear from OP's post whether that is true or not)